# AddIn button disabled in Data View but enabled in Layout View

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, add-in, vb.net

VB.NET Addin for ArcMap 10.3 may be causing my Table of Contents to constantly refresh. I have a custom toolbar with a few buttons. I want all of the buttons to be disabled when in Data View and only be enabled in Layout View. I believe that this code works, but is there a better way to do this?

Instead of putting this code on each button, can it be applied to the whole toolbar instead? I put a line of code to write a snippet of text to a log file when the OnUpdate routine is called and the file quickly got huge. That leads me to believe that this code is constantly running.

```
Public Class btn_DrawBorder
    Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
    Private m_Application As IApplication
    Private m_MxDoc As IMxDocument
    Public Sub New()
        m_Application = My.ArcMap.Application
        m_MxDoc = My.ArcMap.Document
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnUpdate()
        If TypeOf m_MxDoc.ActiveView Is IPageLayout Then
            Enabled = True
        ElseIf TypeOf m_MxDoc.ActiveView Is IMap Then
            Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```